# How to debug why emojis are not being emmited via socket.io properly to an android device using https but are using http

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

I have managed to create a real-time chat app using node.js and socket.io and an android phone using the socket.io library. I decided to get it working using https, and while it does work for basic English characters, the android phone fails to emit/receive emojis or Cyrillic characters for example.

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');




 var server = https.createServer(
            { 
                key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/privkey.pem'),
                 cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/cert.pem'),
                  ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/chain.pem'),
                    requestCert: false,
                    rejectUnauthorized: false 
             },
             function(req, res) {
     });
});
// Loading socket.io
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.to(message.room).emit('message',{"message":"sample text with \ud83d\udc0b"});
```

On my android device, it recieves

```
JsonObject: {"message":"sample text with \u000b"}
```

However in http, when the server is simply

```
var https = require('http');
var server = https.createServer(

             function(req, res) {
     });
});
```

The Android device gets the message with the emoji properly. I am baffled as to how I am supposed to debug this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this issue? I’m having a similar issue  today.

Comment: I actually did figure a way out around this, for it to work I had to encode the message in BASE_64 and decode it on the android app. This would allow the emojis and cyrillic characters to go through without being disturbed.